# Chrome Extension V3 content.js giving "Uncaught ReferenceError: [function] is not defined" but Function Exists

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my 1st attempt at a Chrome Extension. **I am able get the extension to run and render an overlay over the browser and create the select in the overlay**. The issue is when I change the select which calls another function (e.g. fieldCheck) in the content.js script, I get an error or "**Uncaught ReferenceError: fieldCheck is not defined**". I know the function is there and the code works as a snippet. I'm obviously overlooking something here? Below is a shortened version of content.js code that produces the error.

```
[content.js]
var ENV;
var envArray = [
    ['Start Here', ''],
    ['OAO Consumer', 'consumer'],
    ['OAO SME', 'sme']
];

function fieldCheck(currID) {
console.log(currID);
};

function createEnvSel() {
    ENV = document.createElement("select");
    ENV.setAttribute("id", "envSel");
    ENV.setAttribute("onchange", "fieldCheck('envSel')");
    for (var i = 0; i < envArray.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = envArray[i][1];
        option.text = envArray[i][0];
        ENV.appendChild(option);
    }
};

function createToolLabels() {
    var cD1 = document.getElementById('cDiv1');
    cD1.innerHTML += 'Pixel Auditing Tool';
};

function createOverlay() {
    var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");

    parentDiv.setAttribute("id", "pDiv");

    parentDiv.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top:0; right:0; float:right; width:640px; height: 490px; padding: 15px; z-index: 100; border: 3px solid black; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;");

    var child1Div = document.createElement("div");

    child1Div.setAttribute("id", "cDiv1");

    child1Div.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; top:0; left:0; float:left; width:598px; height: 30px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 30px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px;  font-weight: normal; color : #000000;");

    var child2Div = document.createElement("div");

    child2Div.setAttribute("id", "cDiv2");

    child2Div.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; top:0; left:0; float:left; width:604px; height: 140px; background-color: #D7E3BF; border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF;");

    var child2Div1 = document.createElement("div");

    child2Div1.setAttribute("id", "cDiv2-1");

    child2Div1.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; left:0; float:left; width:302px; height:70px; border: align-content: center; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;  font-weight: bold; display: flex; align-items: center; padding-left: 15px;");

    var txtENV = document.createTextNode('Environment :');

    child2Div1.appendChild(txtENV);

    createEnvSel();

    child2Div1.append(ENV);

    child2Div.append(child2Div1);

    parentDiv.append(child1Div, child2Div);

    document.body.appendChild(parentDiv);
};

function createPixelAuditTool() {
    createOverlay();
    createToolLabels();
};

createPixelAuditTool();
```

I did try setting the function to the window scope but still had the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A content script runs in an "isolated world", meaning that its JavaScript functions/variables cannot be seen by the web page's scripts, including the inline event handlers like `onchange` attribute.

Replace this:

```js
// bad
ENV.setAttribute("onchange", "fieldCheck('envSel')");
```

with the following code that sets the function directly:

```js
// good
ENV.onchange = evt => fieldCheck('envSel');
```